# Cordova/Phonegap enable authentication cookies set by server

Tags: ajax, authentication, cordova, cookies

I have a Cordova application that needs to access data from a protected backend (webSeal). First the app would do a POST to retrive a token. Then for every request to get or set data it will include this token as a authentication header as such:

Authentication: Bearer {{token}}

The webSeal then does a cookie authentication also so it will send back cookies to the app.

It appears that I'm not getting these cookies back. If I do the requset in a rest client such as postman it works and I can see the cookies in the inspector. In the app I use jquery ajax for the request.

Can anyone please help me with this head scratcher?

Comment: I think it is something do with cross-origin-request. Have you enabled cross-origin in phonegap? I am assuming that your first(origin) `index.html` file is located in the phonegap App directory and subsequent request are to the `webSeal` URL.

Comment: Yes, the index.html in within the "www/" project folder. Do you need to enable cross-origin in phonegap or is it not enough to "white-list" all domains (<access origin="*" />) in config.xml? How would you enable cross-origin in phonegap? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: CORS doesn't apply to phonegap, because the webapp is served using the file:// protocol (which may not be supported by server side CORS implementation). You should be fine using just phonegap's whitelist for this.

Comment: Cordova doesn't prevent cross domain requests because the app isn't "on a domain". You are your own domain 'self' and all requests are external. So CORS doesn't apply.

Answer (score -2):

i was facing the same problem but due to some platform errors i advise you to forget about cookies and use [localstorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: localstorage is not a solution for cookies. These are entirely unrelated things.

Comment: Yes indeed @Flimzy, however, localstorage can provide the persistent storage element for an authentication system, should cookies not be an option, e.g. storing a JSON Web Token in localstorage, which you pass up with requests, for your server to validate.